# duplicated column name when using join with Zend_Db_table

Tags: zend-db-table

I have two tables. Both of them have a column named 'title'. When I use the following code snippet to join two tables, I can't access one of the title column.

```
    $select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $select->join("service","service.id = lecture.service_id");
    return $select;
```

is there a way to access both columns?

Answer (score 9):

You need to rename one of the columns so it doesn't conflict with the other. If you pass an array as the optional 3rd argument to join(), you can specify which columns to retrieve from the joined table. If one or more of the entries in the array is hashed, then the hash key will be used as the property name. With the code below, you can refer to the title column of the service table as "service_title" in your query results. If you want other columns from the service table, add them to the array, with or without hashes as desired.

```
$select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->join("service", "service.id = lecture.service_id",
              array("service_title" => "service.title");
return $select;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$select = $this->select();
$select->from(array('t'=>'table1'), array('table_title AS title_first','table_sendo_colun','table_third_colun'));
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->join("service","service.id = t.service_id");
return $select;
```

Maybe It can do the job.

Regard´s.

Comment: Dude, I've been looking all over for this answer. Thanks for the great idea.